# Existentially quantified types example fails in ghc 7.2.2

Tags: haskell, ghc, higher-rank-types

According to Wikipedia, the following code should compile,

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
data T = MkT (exists a. Show a => a)
```

But, I'm not having any luck. ghci 7.2.2 complains with,

```
test.hs:2:23:
    Illegal symbol '.' in type
    Perhaps you intended -XRankNTypes or similar flag
    to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The original link is here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use the `ExistentialQuantification` flag to do this without `GADTs`

Comment: @is7s, Thanks, the answer "Existentials are subsumed by GADTs" is particularly helpful for me since I'm familiar with them in that context.

Answer (score 5):

The page you linked mentions that `exists` as a keyword doesn't exist but that you can get the same behavior using `forall`. Note that your particular example is captioned "(psuedo) haskell".

They say it would be equivalent to:

```
data T = forall a. MkT a
```

with

```
MkT :: forall a. a -> T
```

Comment: oh, duh, thanks! In this case, it is as powerful as having an actual `exists`, right? I wanted to write some "f :: a -> exists t. t", but I see this is wrong for a number of reasons ... I'll probably have to use generics somehow ...

Comment: I think it's just as powerful, but I've also only started learning about existential types recently :)

Comment: If you want to include the `Show a` context, it becomes `data T = forall a. (Show a) => MkT a`. If I'm not mistaken, [UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) actually supports `exists` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

in ghci mode, it should be like this.

`ghci> :set -XRankNTypes`